# Merge multiple values in one column into same cell

Tags: excel, excel-2013

EDIT: The intended output is to have one spreadsheet of the untouched IDs and commodity categories, and one spreadsheet with 1 occurrence of ID with the commodity categories combined. This is because I'm writing reports on total number of commodities and total number of unqiue incidents.

I have a spreadsheet that has an ID number across multiple rows with a commodity category and what I need to do is get the commodity categories associated with that ID number into the same cell. I'm seeing a lot of stuff about INDEX/MATCH but I'm not sure how it applied to my specific example.

Most examples are outputting data from the same column into the same row/multiple columns or something slightly different. I need to do this row about 600 rows and all have varying amount of rows and values. Some IDs have only one value, some have 40 values, and some have 2. Appreciate the help.

The intended input/output is below.
EX:

```
ID               Commodity Category
A01-0301         Food and Beverage
A01-0301         Apparel and Accessories
A01-0301         Food and Beverage
A01-0302         Other   

ID               Commodity Category
A01-0301         Food and Beverage, Apparel and Accessories, Food and Beverage
A01-0302         Other
```

Comment: Yes. The example I had is very short compared to the actual spreadsheet. The actual sheet includes values, GPS lat/long, address time, date, commodity 'drilldowns' and a handwritten commodity description. What I need to do is preserve the first spreadsheet with all the commodity rows and make a unique count spreadsheet with just one ID number because I'm reporting on unique IDs (ex, we had 500 incident IDs generated from TX, 300 from CA and 200 from UT) and also reporting on all of the commodities and how frequently they were mentioned. I'm going to expand on my question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

'Dirty' but might be adequate, assuming ID is in A1:

Sort by `ID`, copy last populated cell in ColumnA down one cell.  In C2:

```
=IF(A1=A2,C1&","&B2,B2)
```

in D2:

```
=A2=A3
```

Select all, Copy, Paste Special, Values over the top, filter ColumnD to select `TRUE` and delete visible, adjust bottom entry.